# Permutations of two rotating groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

4 roommates want to rotate who parks in a 2 car garage. They want to maximize time in the garage, minimize extended time parking outside, maximize irregularity of pattern. How does one calculate the patterns wrt rate of cycle and offset of the two groups?

Answer (score 0):

A simple system would be to randomly select two cars for the garage on day $1$ and then on day $2$, swap them for the other two cars. Now repeat this process. This would gurantee that no car parks outside more than two days in a row and the pattern would be irregular.